# Bash parameter reference

Tags: linux, bash

I want to refer to a parameter in bash by using a number generated by a sum. How do I do this?

More specifically:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    $sum=${$1}
    echo $sum
```

When I execute the script ./script.bash A B C D, if $sum = 3, then I want to return C. How do I do this, does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the indirect expansion syntax:

```
${!parameter}
```

as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

(Also note that variable assignments should not have a `$` on the left-hand side!)

Example:

```
$ cat script.bash 
#!/bin/bash

sum=3
arg=${!sum}
echo $arg
$ ./script.bash A B C D
C
$
```